# Why are basic functions in Elixir (i.e. length/1) under the default Kernel module?

Tags: elixir

The Kernel module in Elixir provides a lot of functionality, and by default is imported anywhere without requiring the prefix `Kernel`. However, many of these functions act only on a particular data type.

The ones that stand out to me are those that operate on lists, like [`length/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#length/1), `hd/1`, and `tl/1`. Elixir already has a [`List` module](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/List.html), so why were these functions not included in the List module (i.e. `List.length/1`)?

I understand for commonly used functions that it is shorter and more convenient, but would it then not have been to duplicate the functionality in a module like `List` using an alias? Are there language conventions or a technical limitations that would have made this difficult given that these functions are implemented as macros and inlined by the compiler.?

Answer (score 2):

I am definitely not familiar enough to give any good answer.

But my guess will be the primary reason is to make thing easier, especially for a beginner. `Kernel` module basically only contain function that delegate to erlang BIF like `:erlang.length(list)` and the rest are mostly important language construct Macros like (`defmacro`, `defmodule`) and some handy ones like (`and`, `unless`. And it actually make sense to load Kernal module as the default environment.

And for the reason why length is in `Kernal` instead of `List`, I guess it's mostly because of following erlang convention in which functions like `length` is put in `erlang` module as BIF.

Comment: That's a good point, I hadn't thought to compare against Erlang documentation. It looks like length in Erlang is also in the default namespace rather than the List module (http://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html).

Answer (score 1):

Elixir Kernel mainly consists of basic language primitives, macros, and guard for pattern matching. Those functions, like length/1, hd/1, and tl/1 in Kernal module are inlined by the Elixir compiler into their Erlang counterparts in  :erlang module. Some of the functions like length/1 can be used in guards and others are for compiler optimizations.

Those basic functions provide basic capabilities for Elixir standard library to build on top of. For example, List.zip/1 uses is_list/1 guard for pattern matching.

One of the reasons why the Elixir core team did not include those functions and operators in List module is that [Elixir doesn't alias functions for discoverability.](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/issues/3853#issuecomment-146741170)